# Click event of radiobutton using javascript in HTML5

Tags: jquery, css, html

I want to get the click event of radio button using jquery in HTML5 using Dot net. I have two radio button in accordion panel when i click on any one off radio button of accordion panel another panel should get open but it not
My jquery code is as follows :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#radioinstant").click(function () {

        $(".flip").hide();
        $(".panel").hide();
        $(".flip1").show();
        $(".panel1").show();
    });
});
```

But i m not able to check whether the radio button is click or not and could not able to open another panel.

Comment: where is you markup? post that

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Write a function which passes the value of the clicked radio button to show and hide what you want to show or hide:

```
function Getvalue(id) {
        if (id == "your radio button id") {
           //do what you want
        }
        else{
            // do what you want
        }
```

Comment: He is wanting to determine whether or not the radio button is checked, not what the ID of the button is, also there is no need to create a function for this, it can be attached to the click event of the radio buttons.

Comment: here the function is created in script and onclick event of radio button the function is called.we give id to radio button match the id of radio button in if condition and show/hide the panel what he wants

Answer (score 0):

Not sure..but give this a try..$(document).ready(function () {

```
$("#youraccordionid #radioinstant").click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault(); //preventing the default behaviour of accordion

    $(".flip").hide();
    $(".panel").hide();
    $(".flip1").show();
    $(".panel1").show();
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".flip1").click(function()
   {

         do what u want here
    });

  $(".flip2").click(function()
   {

     do what u want here
    });

 });

and keep this tags 

 <input name="rad1" type="radio" class="flip1"> radio1  </p>
 <input name="rad1" type="radio" class="flip2"> radio2  </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

What is #radioinstant? If you put id="radionistant" on each of your radio buttons, it will not work. IDs must be unique and result of duplicate IDs depends on the browser. It will work if id="radioinstant" is on an element that contains all the radios because the event will bubble up to it, but be warned that it will also fire if you click on #radioinstant itself or any other element in it.

If you want to bind an event to multiple elements, do it by class (give all radios the same class) or by element type (bind to all radios on the page). You can also narrow down the binding by using "#container input:radio" or "#container .radio_class".

You can also check if a specific radio is checked. It's the same as for checkbox:

```
if ($('.radio_1').is(':checked')) {
    //something
}
else if ($('.radio_1').is(':checked')) {
    //something else
}
//etc
```

You can also select the checked radio with $('input:radio:checked') and check it's class or value or whatever.